# How get current country name in java?

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

I want to get current country name in java . I use this code.

```
private HttpServletRequest request; 
Locale currentCountry = request.getLocale();  
System.out.println(currentCountry.getDisplayCountry());
```

But it through an NullPointerException like Caused by: `java.lang.NullPointerException`. at 2nd line. Please Help me  anyone.

Comment: Do you know what a NullPointerException is?

Comment: Which Country Name? Server, Client?

Comment: Thanks Jens . I want Client Country name .

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

The snippet of code is not enough to tell why you got the Null Pointer. I assume you are use servlet on server side.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServletBean {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        Locale userlocale = request.getLocale();
        out.println("Your Country : " + userlocale.getCountry());

        out.println();
        out.println("");
    }
}
```